# How do I use or insert the Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header into my AngularJS code or am I trying to use the wrong code for my situation?

Tags: c#, angularjs, json

I have the following bit of script in AngularJS pulling a JSON array from a url.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('recordsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://{erased section}.amazonaws.com/prod/load/1").then(function (response) {
      $scope.records = response.data;
  });
});
</script>
```

It works fine. But note that at the end of the url is a 1. It's the first of ten files. Most of them work fine and I can get the data and work with it. But on the 3rd, 5th and 6th files it just displays nothing when in the above code.

when I put it in the browser in the debugger I found it saying: "no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the URL requested source". I've looked at several posts regarding this error message and I've tried to implement them in Angular code, I've even gone and implemented them in ASP.NET WebForms where I saw code for that:

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
  </customHeaders>
```

But I think I must be doing something wrong as far as how or where I am inserting the code into my own, or maybe missing some other aspect, as while no other errors show up and in Visual Studio it builds and runs, I'm still not receiving the JSON file from the url.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss: `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET"/>`

Comment: I added that in but nothing :(